# Customizing inline error message in mailchimp embed forms

Tags: mailchimp

I have embedded a mailchimp form in my website (completely with js code), and couldn't find a way to customize the inline error messages.

How may I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The text of error messages should be customizable through the General forms (not Embedded forms) area, by selecting the 'Translate it' tab for each form.

As for styling you’ll likely have to inspect the elements/CSS generated by the js and write new CSS for them.

Comment: Thank you. I understood the limitation. Now I have used a custom form with their API.